# Why Confidence does not consider B in Association rule mining

Tags: data-mining, rule

For the ARM rule A->B, confidence can be calculated as AUB/A, which gives you out of all transactions in which A is present, how many have A and B together.

My feeling is that in confidence calculation we are giving more importance to A rather than B. But B should also be considered equally valuable in determining the importance of a rule.

Precisely, I want to say that there should be another term (may be called inverse of confidence) which equals AUB/B.

Any kind of explanations are welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation wasn't chosen for fun or intuition.

There is a reason why the rule is A -> B, and not A <- B...

The mathematical reason to define it this way is called **conditional probabilitiy**.

The decision rule A -> B is a conditional rule. If A then B. Not the other way round... the formula you propose is for if B then A.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. So, for equation AUB/B and rule A->B, does it give any kind of information about B?

Comment: Yes. It gives the conditional probability of B, if A is known to be true. This is a pretty strong information...